# Bitwise or on a variable amount of numbers C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, itext, bitwise-operators

I am building an upload form for iTextSharp using the MVC4 framework and I'm getting stuck trying to translate Boolean values to a bitwise integer.

The method iTextSharp offers uses bitwise or to combine multiple parameters like so:

```
    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(new PdfReader(
                    ms.ToArray()),
                    fs,
                    true, 
                    null, 
                    "Pw", 
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN .......);
```

However, I defined my model to use Boolean properties so it's easy to hook to a webform.

```
internal static class PermissionConstants
{
    public const int NumAllowAssembly = 1024;
    public const int NumAllowCopy = 16;
    public const int NumAllowDegradedPrinting = 4;
    public const int NumAllowFillIn = 256;
    public const int NumAllowModifyAnnotations = 32;
    public const int NumAllowModifyContents = 8;
    public const int NumAllowPrinting = 2052;
    public const int NumAllowScreenReaders = 512;
    public const int NumHideMenubar = 8192;
    public const int NumHideToolbar = 4096;
    public const int NumHideWindowUI = 16384;
}

public class Permissions
{
    public bool AllowAssembly { get; set; }
    public bool AllowCopy { get; set; }
    public bool AllowDegradedPrinting { get; set; }
    public bool AllowFillIn { get; set; }
    public bool AllowModifyAnnotations { get; set; }
    public bool AllowModifyContents { get; set; }
    public bool AllowPrinting { get; set; }
    public bool AllowScreenReaders { get; set; }
    //[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool HideMenubar { get; set; }
    //[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool HideToolbar { get; set; }
    //[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool HideWindowUI { get; set; }

    public Permissions()
    {
        HideMenubar = true;
        HideToolbar = true;
        HideWindowUI = true;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is sending the values from the Permissions Class to the first method.  I'd like to make a method that generates the right number.  Does anyone know how to do this? Is it possible to just add integers?  I don't think that results in the same numbers as the bitwise or operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a combination of "flag" `enum`s from a set of `bool`s as follows:

```
Permissions p = ...
var res = (p.AllowCopy   ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY : 0)
        | (p.AllowFillIn ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN : 0)
        | // ...and so on.
```

Comment: Of cource, I never realized I could just do it that way.
Thank you very much!